# How to get coq to print out new goal and hypotheses after applying tactic

Tags: coq

sometimes I find coq gets into a state where when I apply a tactic, the new goal and hypotheses don't automatically get printed out.  How do I set it to print these out after each tactic invocation.

This is coq 8.7.2, using coqtop

Comment: What is your Coq version? What user interface are you using?

Comment: I'm not OP but I've seen this happen with Proof General, but I haven't investigated why. In the meantime, you can use C-c C-p to refresh the goal window.

Comment: I believe this is more a problem with older versions of ProofGeneral than with newer ones

Comment: I opened an issue with a minimized example https://github.com/ProofGeneral/PG/issues/403

Answer (score 1):

I believe when this happens it's a bug in Proof General, which is supposed to display the proof context whenever you're in the middle of a proof. Li-yao Xia's solution of hitting `C-c C-p` should work.